# Are Floats' Bit Patterns Ordered?

Tags: java, encoding, floating-point, floating-point-precision

Looking at the IEEE float/double representation

```
[mantissa sign][signed exponent][unsigned mantissa]
```

Am I correct to assume that sorting these values numerically always results in the same as sorting the bit patterns themselves lexicographically?

My other question then is how do I obtain the bits (or rather bytes) of the bit pattern (of the IEEE representation) of a float/double in Java? (Or alternatively just on the HotSpot JVM, if the internal representation isn't specified.)

How would I construct an IEEE-like representation for arbitrary-precision Decimals (like `java.math.BigDecimal`)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Just for starters, negative numbers have a 1 in the high order bit, so they would sort AFTER the positive numbers.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Same happens with signed integer types.

Comment: @JimGarrison: So assuming I flip the one bit myself in the bit pattern, is there anything else preventing me from sorting the values by bit-pattern?

Comment: If the floating point number is negative then you have to flip all the rest of the bits to keep the sorted order.

Comment: Jesus.  No.  You don't have to touch anything.  Negative numbers sort before positive numbers and that's fine.

Comment: @tmyklebu: If the bits of the float/double are left untouched, and reinterpreted as the bits of a signed two's complement integer of appropriate width, negative numbers will sort in the reverse order to the normal numeric order.  E.g., the result of sorting `[1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -2.0]` will be `[-1.0, -2.0, 1.0. 2.0]`.  So yes, negative numbers sort before positive numbers, but you don't get the usual numeric ordering this way.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Correct.  I should update my answer.  Pity I can't update my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorting by bit pattern is sufficient, but not necessary, to sort numerically.  (There are signed zeroes and NaNs to harsh your style.)

You can access the bit pattern of a `double` using `Double.doubleToLongBits()` and of a `float` using `Float.floatToIntBits()`.

**EDIT**:  As Mark Dickinson points out, this sorts negative numbers backward.  The following transformation gives you something sufficient, but not necessary, to sort numerically:

```
longbits ^= (longbits >> 63) & 0x7fffffffffffffff;
```

The effect here is to xor the sign bit with all other bits.  This transformation is its own inverse; apply it once before and once after sorting.

Comment: Sufficient but not necessary is fine - I'm looking for a fixed-length encoding that's reversible and trivially sortable.

Comment: @Dexter The raw bits will be fine.

Comment: So how do I deal with the negatives then?

Comment: Xor the sign bit with all of the lower bits before and after sorting.